# right align link items containing image and text along navbar

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a right aligned navbar. Each link item should contain an image and a text. When having text only this code works fine

```css
#navbar {
  height: 60px;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: end;
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
  align-items: center;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 10px;
  color: white;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <div>
    <a href="/">Home</a>
    <a href="/about">About</a>
    <a href="/projects">Projects</a>
    <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="/imprint">Imprint</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I added images and texts to the link item and built a wrapper around these elements.

```css
#navbar {
  height: 60px;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: end;
  padding: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  background: red;
}

#navbarLinkContainer {
  margin: 0 60px;
}

.navbarItemContainer {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.navbarItemImg {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <div id="navbarLinkContainer">
    <a class="navbarItemContainer" href="/">
      <div>
        <img class="navbarItemImg" src="https://discordapp.com/assets/19654c38399b0e75c351d6fc960fe0ca.svg">
        <div class="navbarItemTitle">Home</div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a class="navbarItemContainer" href="/about">
      <div>
        <img class="navbarItemImg" src="https://discordapp.com/assets/19654c38399b0e75c351d6fc960fe0ca.svg">
        <div class="navbarItemTitle">About</div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a class="navbarItemContainer" href="/projects">
      <div>
        <img class="navbarItemImg" src="https://discordapp.com/assets/19654c38399b0e75c351d6fc960fe0ca.svg">
        <div class="navbarItemTitle">Projects</div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately the CSS breaks now. How can I fix it so that each link item is aligned to the right, centered vertically and is placed along the navbar?

I achieved it using `flexbox`

https://jsfiddle.net/q48tyuac/

but maybe there is a better solution using the `grid` attribute. Because when you lower the screen size these elements are fixed and I would like them to break to the next row if there is no space left.

Comment: "*maybe there is a better solution using the grid attribute*" - this is a flexbox area :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `flex-wrap:wrap;`

```
#navbar {
  /* height: 60px; */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 20px;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  align-items: center;
  background: red;
  /*  margin: 0 60px; */
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6p03s5cm/

Answer (score 1):

if you dont want to use flexbox with grid you can target `#navbarLinkContainer` and do it with columns

```css
#navbar {
      
      display: grid;
      justify-items: end;
      padding: 20px;
      align-items: center;
      background: red;
    }

    #navbarLinkContainer {
     
      display:grid;
      grid-template-columns:repeat(3 , 1fr) ;
      
    }

    .navbarItemContainer {
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      margin: 0 10px;
    }

    .navbarItemImg {
      width: 64px;
      height: 64px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <div id="navbarLinkContainer">
    <a class="navbarItemContainer" href="/">
      <div>
        <img class="navbarItemImg" src="https://discordapp.com/assets/19654c38399b0e75c351d6fc960fe0ca.svg">
        <div class="navbarItemTitle">Home</div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a class="navbarItemContainer" href="/about">
      <div>
        <img class="navbarItemImg" src="https://discordapp.com/assets/19654c38399b0e75c351d6fc960fe0ca.svg">
        <div class="navbarItemTitle">About</div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a class="navbarItemContainer" href="/projects">
      <div>
        <img class="navbarItemImg" src="https://discordapp.com/assets/19654c38399b0e75c351d6fc960fe0ca.svg">
        <div class="navbarItemTitle">Projects</div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Your example works but the items get pushed to the right side on lower screens :( It seems the other solution fits better ..

Comment: yeah i usualy use flex for this situation but because you mentioned grid so i wanted to give you an idea so you want them when its on smaller screen to be centered?

Comment: no, but I want them to stay on screen. If you lower the screen size they get pushed to the right (outside of the screen)